# Stock Market Hours Cron Job

Tags: azure, cron

I am setting up an Azure function that needs to run during U.S. stock market hours (9:30 AM to 4:00 PM). I want the function to run every 15 minutes. I am new to cron expressions so I am wondering, Is this correct?

```
*/30 9 * * 1-5 <command>
*/15 10-15 * * 1-5 <command>
0 16 * * 1-5 <command>
```

The idea here is to run at 9:30, then run every 15 minutes from 9 AM to 3 PM (which I'm guessing means it stops at 3:45). And then run again at 4 PM.

Comment: Tried to edit this question but not sure how. The cron expressions should be on 3 lines, with the command tag indicating the end of the line:
*/30 9 * * 1-5 <command>
*/15 10-15 * * 1-5 <command>
0 16 * * 1-5 <command>

Comment: You have to indent code blocks by four blanks, or wrap them in triple backtick (`\`\`\``) lines.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Will keep in mind for the future.

Comment: I think the first entry should be `30,45 9 * * 1-5`, or you skip 9:45.

Comment: https://crontab.guru/ is pretty useful to check.

Comment: I think you're right Ben. I will modify it in the function. Thanks much.